# "Notes" vs "OneNote" in Graph API Endpoint - which is correct?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

[Official documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/resources/onenote.md) for retrieving OneNote documents under an Office 365 Group states to use the URi format:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/{version}/groups/{id}/onenote/{notebooks | sections | sectionGroups | pages}`

Constructing a GET request of the format:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}/onenote/notebooks`

fails for me, with a 400 error. No detailed information on why it failed is returned. If I run the same query through Graph Explorer, I get `Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: groups/d11c2cd1-8b41-48ee-b512-93921e19f741/onenote/notebooks`

**However, the following URL does work:**

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}/notes/notebooks`

Note the difference here, using "notes" instead of "onenote". This works from the command line for me (PowerShell) and using Graph Explorer. I can also substitute "notebooks" here, for "pages" or "sections" and again this works with PowerShell or Graph Explorer.

Now, [Create Notebook](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/api/onenote_post_notebooks.md) suggests a post to `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}/onenote/notebooks`, and whether I try this, or `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}/notes/notebooks` it still fails either programatically or through Graph Explorer.

It looks as though there used to be some "notes" documentation at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/resources/notes.md but this doesn't exist.

I'm unclear why "onenote" fails for everything, and "notes" works for getting notebooks/pages/sections but not creating a notebook.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are preparing the service for an update and the documentation went live a day before the service update. Stay tuned for a blog post by 5/4/17 that outlines the details of all the updates for the OneNote API.

Comment: Hi Yina. Thanks for the reply. I'm still experiencing the same issue despite the date passing. Which blog can I check for updates? Thank you.

Comment: Can confirm that as of this morning, I tested using the documented `/onenote/notebooks` endpoint (rather than `/notes/notebooks`) and it now works.